# pool connection doesn't have free connections when use hibernate - envers and get history?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

There is application on spring4+jaxb+jpa+hibernate-envers  works on  websphere + oracle11g

there are 2  java-methods, which make get history of User entity:
Method getHistoryUser called from rest - controller, that finds all versions for one id and read from base all users using this id and versions.
extractUsers - just map JPA - enities to String

I have on websphere jdbc-resource with params for base and poolConnection - param. Max available pool connection by default is 10.
And I have an eeror on this value - service doesn't response and all connections are interrupted..
And I can use just workaround for 40 pool connections and it works.

When client calls method getHistoryUser - I have no available connections, can you help and say why?

```
public String getHistoryUser(String id) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "get history id=" + id);
        AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());

        List<Number> auditVersions = auditReader.getRevisions(UserRecord.class, id);
        List<UserRecord> userRecords = auditVersions.stream().map(item -> {
            UserRecord elem = auditReader.find(UserRecord.class, id, item.intValue());
            elem.setVersion(item.intValue());
            return elem;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        extractUsers(UserRecords).stream().forEach(item -> {
            result.append(item);
        });
        return result.toString();
    }



    private List<String> extractUsers(List<UserRecord> userRecords) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "extractUserRecords..");
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(userRecords) || userRecords.stream().allMatch(x -> x == null)) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return riskMetricRecords.stream().map(userRecord -> {
            String userRecord = (String) deserialize(userRecord.getUser());
            return appendMetaInfoInEntity(user, "<User>", userRecord.getPrKey(), Integer.toString(userRecord.getVersion()));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

In my JPA enity there are any fields and @Audit annotations for using hibernate-envers

In logs I saw one interestin warning too..

```
[2/27/19 10:50:32:516 MSK] 00000103 SystemOut     O [2019-02-27 10:50:32.516] WARN  ework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect JDBC Connection to reset not identical to originally prepared Connection - please make sure to use connection release mode ON_CLOSE (the default) and to run against Hibernate 4.2+ (or switch HibernateJpaDialect's prepareConnection flag to false


How to fix this issue. It just code bug or some fueture of hibernate?
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to close entityManager?

Something like this:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
...
entityManager.close();
```

I had this same problem also.